# Count the lines of method in project

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a PHP project and I want to know the list of methods have over 500 lines.

I had used the PhpStorm plugin [statistic](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509-statistic) but it not support to counter for methods.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have a look at the reflection class https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: @jeff I have some idea base on your suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `phpmd/phpmd` with cleancode and  codesize rules for the same out of PHPStorm.

Answer (score 0):

By @jeff suggestions, I create a simple script to get all method's line.
As the output result, can use excel to filter what data I need.

```php
$arrClassName = array_keys(AmAutoLoader::$ClassFileMap);

foreach ($arrClassName as $className) {
  try {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($className);
  } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
    debug($e->getMessage());
    continue;
  }

  $listMethod = $reflector->getMethods();
  foreach ($listMethod as $objMethod) {
    if ($className != $objMethod->class) {
      break;
    }

    $methodName = $objMethod->name;
    $start = $reflector->getMethod($methodName)->getStartLine();
    $end = $reflector->getMethod($methodName)->getEndLine();
    $totalLine = $end - $start;

    // output as you want
  }

}
```